# Calling multiple compiled patterns in a function for re.search

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do a re.search on multiple compiled patterns within a function, but unable to do so. Below is the code:

```
def regex_parameters1():
    a = re.compile(r're1')
    b = re.compile(r're2')
    c = re.compile(r're3')
    d = re.compile(r're4')
    e = re.compile(r're5')
test = re.search(regex_parameters1, text)
for i in test
  if i is not None:
     print(i.group())
```

Getting the following error:
     TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Can anyone please let me know how to go about this? I eventually need only one search function that can call multiple compiled patterns.

Comment: Why did you think the first argument to `re.search` could be a function that defined, but didn't actually return, multiple compiled expressions? That's certainly not in the docs. Are you trying to iterate over those expressions in your for loop? In which case, why not *do that*, return an iterable and have `for i in regex_parameters1():`.

Comment: I am trying to compile all the patterns in a function for changes in future and one search function which can print all the matching patterns within the text.

Comment: thanks for the input, i changed as you mentioned:
for i in regex_parameters1():
     test = re.search(i, sentence)
     print(i, ":", test.group())

got this error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Of course. Because, **again**, that function *does not return anything*. Maybe read other questions with the same error message?

Comment: Sorry, i am completely new to python. can you please let me know how the code can be made to work

Comment: Then start with e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/. This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having a central place for your regular expressions is definitely a good way, if there’s a chance that they might be modified in the future. However, you should also store them in a way that will *not* make it necessary to recompile them whenever you use them. You should just keep the compiled expression around directly.

A common way to do this is to just have constants at the top of your module, something like this:

```
RE_FOO = re.compile('…')
RE_BAR = re.compile('…')
RE_BAZ = re.compile('…')
```

If you have a list of regular expressions which you are *always* using in a sequence, then you should put them in a sequence instead:

```
RE_FOOS = [
    re.compile('…'),
    re.compile('…'),
    re.compile('…')
]
```

Then, when you need to use them, you can simply iterate over them to check them all:

```
for expr in RE_FOOS:
    result = expr.search(text)
    if result:
        break

# do something with result
```

You could even create a helper function to do the search on a text using the first matching expression:

```
def searchFoos (text):
    for expr in RE_FOOS:
        result = expr.search(text)
        if result:
             return result

# And use it directly later
result = searchFoos(text)
if result:
    # Do something with the result
```